# No repeated sqlite results for many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sqlite, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have two tables (Threads and Users)

```
CREATE TABLE users (id integer primary key, email text);
CREATE TABLE "threads"(id integer primary key not null, name text);
```

Since users can have many threads, and, each thread can have many users, I would like to create a many to many relations between them.

So, I am creating another table (Membership):

```
CREATE TABLE membership (
    id integer primary key, 
    thread_id integer, 
    user_id integer, 
    foreign key (thread_id) references threads (id), 
    foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
);
```

I can all the threads and its related membership with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM threads t LEFT JOIN membership ms ON ms.thread_id = t.id;

id          type        name           id          thread_id   user_id   
----------  ----------  -------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           aweseom group  4           1           1         
1           1           aweseom group  3           1           3         
1           1           aweseom group  6           1           4         
2           1           new group      5           2           4
```

Or I can get all the users and its related membership with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN membership ms ON ms.user_id = u.id;

id          email           id          thread_id   user_id   
----------  --------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           first@mail.com  4           1           1         
3           third@mail.com  3           1           3         
4           kakar@gmail.co  6           1           4         
4           kakar@gmail.co  5           2           4
```

As you can see, in both the cases, threads and users are repeated. Since I will be using the SQL results in my react native project ([using Expo's SQLite module](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite.html)) and thread's id or user's id will be used as a key, is there any way to avoid repeated result set so that I can finally have a result in this way:

threads:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "members": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "email": "first@mail.com"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "email": "three@mail.com"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "email": "kakar@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "name": "awesome group",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "members": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "email": "kakar@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "name": "new group",
    }
]
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query outputs a table (with a fixed number of columns and rows). What you want does not have the form of a table.

Just use one query to read the threads, and then for each thread, execute a query to read the corresponding members. This requires N+1 queries, but in SQLite, this [is not a problem](http://www.sqlite.org/np1queryprob.html).